# How can I remove gaps on right and left of divs

Tags: html, css

How can I remove gaps on right and left of divs.

```
#foot_text {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    width: 500px;
    margin: auto;
    padding-top:1px;
}

#foot_wrap {
    width:100%;
    height:60px;
    background-color:#999999;
    min-height:40px !important;
}
```

html:

```
<div id="foot_wrap"></div>
<div id="foot_text"></div>
```

Comment: Can you be more specific? What gaps? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Hi @Balu i think you want this http://tinkerbin.com/pOIfDvr9

Comment: Please use jsfiddle.net to show examples.

Comment: there is around 5px white space on left and right of the box foot_wrap

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[LIve demo](http://tinkerbin.com/pOIfDvr9)**

Hi now write this css

```
.foot_wrap, body{
margin:0;
}
```

Used to `css` **[reset](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/)** for your layout

Comment: Its worth mentioning that you don't need to set the padding on the div since that is "inside" and may be wanted.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem may be not with divs, but with the body tag. As I think the body tag doesn't spread through full page. Make the `margin` of your body zero.

> `<body style="margin:0px;">`

Comment: `margin: 0` on the div may be needed too though you are probably right that the body margin is the main problem.

Answer (score 1):

If `#foot_wrap` division is child of `body` tag, make sure that you have set margin, padding of `body` to 0

```
html, body {
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
}
```

If not, look at its parent element and above properties for that.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
padding-left:0px;
padding-right:0px;
margin-left:0px;
margin-right:0px;
```